# Trouble understanding an article about MFCC

Tags: audio, continuous-signals, mfcc

I'm willing to apply the same audio preparation that [this article page 3.](https://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/AudioToObama/siggraph17_obama.pdf)

However, I don't understand the final part :

```
The final 28-D output feature vector consists of the 13-D vector output from the DCT plus
the log mean energy to account for volume, and their first temporal
derivatives
```

Can someone tell me what's exactly in this final vector and why did the authors chose to use such a method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the output of the Discrete Cosine Transform gives a 13-vector. To this, they append the log mean energy. That gives a 14-vector.

They then subtract from this the previous 14-vector to yield another 14-vector, which they concatenate with the existing 14-vector.

That gives a 28-vector.

I suspect the log mean energy is just:
$$
{\tt LME} = \log\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{N} x_n^2 \right)
$$
where $N$ is the length of the frame used.

Comment: Thank you sir, do you know what they mean by log mean energy ? Is it just log(E(x**2))) ?

Comment: @Tiffany Please see my update.